# Indefinite integral of du=(x^2+y^2)dx/y solution check

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is the solution to the ODE $$\text{$\int $du=$\int
   $}\frac{\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{y}\text{dx}$$
equals to $$u=c+\frac{x^3}{3 y}+\text{yx}?$$

Comment: That's not what's normally called an ODE.

Comment: It is, however, correctly evaluated -- assuming $y$ is independent of $x$ and $u$.

Comment: To check your work, you could take the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$. You'll find that it's equal to your original integrand.